# Cascading dropdownlists in asp.net mvc : Inserting selected values in database in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have to display a dropdownlist from another dropdownlist and that works with me but the problem is that when I insert selected values in database it didn't insert values of product's Reference or poste's Number,it inserts the productId and postId.
I didn't know how to solve this problem.
**Controller:**

```
   public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ProduitList = new SelectList(db.Produits, "idProduit", "Reference");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Gabarits/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(GabaritViewModel gabarit, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string strPoste = Request["poste"].ToString();
            var uploadDir = "~/Images";
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(uploadDir, fileName);

            //file.SaveAs(path);

            var reference = gabarit.Reference.ToString();
            var poste = gabarit.Numero.ToString();
            var CB = (reference + strPoste + gabarit.Exemplaire);
            int CodeB = Convert.ToInt32(CB);

            var dbgabarit = new Gabarit()
            {
                Designation = gabarit.Designation,
                Produit = gabarit.idProduit,
                Photo = path,
                Poste = Convert.ToInt32(strPoste),
                Exemplaire = gabarit.Exemplaire,
                CodeBarre = CodeB
            };

           gabaritrepository.Insert(dbgabarit);
            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ProduitList = new SelectList(db.Produits, "idProduit", "Reference",gabarit.idProduit);
        ViewBag.PosteList = new SelectList(db.Postes, "idPoste", "Numero", gabarit.idPoste);

        return View(gabarit);
    }

    public JsonResult ChoisirPoste(int ID)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        return Json(db.Postes.Where(p => p.idProduit == ID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View:**

```
<script>
//script for cascading dropdownlists: Produit=>Poste
$(function() {
    $("#IDProduit").change(function() {

        $.get("/Gabarits/ChoisirPoste", { ID: $("#IDProduit").val() }, function (data) {

            $("#IDPoste").empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, row) {

                $("#IDPoste").append(" <option value='" + row.idPoste + "'>" + row.Numero + "</option>");
            });
        })
    });
});
```

### Create

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Gabarits", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Gabarit</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Designation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Designation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Designation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })
            </div>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reference, "Produit", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(p=>p.idProduit, ViewBag.ProduitList as SelectList, htmlAttributes: new {id = "IDProduit", @class = "form-control"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reference, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Numero, "Poste", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select id="IDPoste" class="form-control" name="poste"></select>

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Numero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Exemplaire, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Exemplaire, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Exemplaire, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Aren't you telling the drop down list to be built using the product id and post id in your code?  Specifically in your controller where you declare the `ViewBag.ProduitList` and `ViewBag.PosteList` you are grabbing their respective ID's.  I believe you would want to grab whatever attribute you cared to show and pass and store it in the model to pass to the view instead of the ID.

Comment: Even when i change gabarit.idProduit by gabarit.Reference in ViewBag.ProduitList it does'nt change anything :( @MichaelPlatt

Comment: Ok try this.  Where you are declaring your `SelectList` change the value of the second parameter to what you want to pass.  So in this case it would look something like this: `ViewBag.ProduitList = new SelectList(db.Produits, "Reference", "Reference");`

Comment: @MichaelPlatt in this case the second dropdownlist disappears

Comment: If you want a second drop down list you'll need to create another select list in the Controller, add it to the viewbag, and display it on the page.  Looking through your View, there isn't a reference to any second dropdown list.